# Can someone help me with the math to calculate a Sol to Jupiter orbit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

Writing sci-fi; my space vehicle just did an Obeth maneuver around the sun, has fusion engines, accelerated all the way down and at 1.5 g at periapsis, so very high initial velocity (750,000 kph? I don't know what's reasonable) and a tight solar orbit (10 million km?). Lost engine, have to coast away from Sol for two or three days, losing velocity to Sol's gravity; then it can thrust at up to 2/10 g. I need the ship to take a couple of months to get to Jupiter orbit, thrusting half the time or less. There are plenty of relativistic spaceship calculators online, but none I can find factor in climbing out of a gravity well from a star, or the increased distance travelled in the curved trajectory of an orbit (as opposed to a straight line, e.g., Jupiter @ aphelion is 5.46 AU out, but you'll follow a considerably longer curve going there.

Is anyone here able to help me with the math?

Comment: You may find helpful and useful: There is [Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/),which is made "for writers/artists using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings".

Comment: This really isn't any more topical than your [now deleted post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294859/acceleration-needed-to-go-sun-to-jupiter-in-a-few-months) from last month. The "homework-like" close reason isn't about *why* you are asking us to walk you through a basic problem; it's about helping you to *learn* by making you focus on why things are a certain way and about us not work as a Mechanical Turk.